# Password change by TFDGUIxLoginDialog

Tags: mysql, delphi, change-password, firedac

I am trying to implement changing of password in MySQL DataBase using FireDAC. Unfortunately, RAD XE5 Help system lacks information on `TFDGUIxLoginAction` (parameter of this type is used in Execute method of `TFDGUIxLoginDialog`). Google gives 5 links, all with no details or something like this:

> Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional
>   information. Please help us document this topic by using the
>   Discussion page!

There is no access to sources of FireDAC.*.pas to see the possible methods. Does anyone have any considerations how to use `TFDGUIxLoginDialog` for this purpose?

Extension of my question to answer the requests from comments:
Of course, `TFDGUIxLoginDialog` has an `Execute` method with a single parameter of `TFDGUIxLoginAction` type. Variables of this type are 8 bytes long and do not have `Create` method. The `Execute` method can be run with `nil` parameter. In this case a standard login dialog is shown. `TFDGUIxLoginDialog` shurely can be used for changing of passwords (at least, expired). Delphi help system mentions this. I tried to find types of `TFDGUIxLoginAction` in FireDAC.Comp.UI.dcu file but failed. I am using an old version of MySQL - 5.1.73. Connections to it are possible from Delphi XE5, that I am currently coding with.

Comment: Can you guess possible param values and their meaning with code completion ([Ctrl+Space])?

Comment: The `TFDGUIxLoginAction` is a pure `procedure of object` that you can pass to the `Execute` method and that will be executed after the user successfully enters the database credentials.

Comment: The support for MySQL v 5.6 password changing was introduced in FireDAC XE6. Also before that was several issues in TFDGUIxLoginDialog.

Comment: Dear René Hoffmann, TLama and da-soft, Thank you for your contribution, I have corrected my question. Hope, I could answer your requests.